# Splash image renders sideways for iPad app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an iPad application that only supports landscape mode (just for a demo I am doing) eventually it will support both.  I want my app to launch in landscape mode and display my splash image.  The app launches correctly in landscape mode however my image is displayed rotated to the left.  The image file is in Landscape mode so I cannot understand why it is doing this.  Any ideas?

Here is my plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
    <string>welcome.png</string>
    <key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>SignerIdentity</key>
    <string>Apple iPhone OS Application Signing</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use any UILaunchImageFile nor UIInterfaceOrientation keys on my Info.plist (I don't point to any Default.png file, I just throw into the projet files that are correctly named).

I only use **UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad** and then just include with my project the following files:

Default-LandscapeLeft.png
Default-LandscapeRight.png
Default-Portrait.png
Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png

In your case just use "Default-LandscapeLeft.png" and "Default-LandscapeRight.png" and you should be fine. The only thing graphics-related in my Info.plist is:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```